# XNA - Can't change sprite position (move it by keyboard input)

Tags: c#, animation, xna, position, sprite

For my first project with XNA, I followed a tutorial which explain how to make a little square face jumping between tiles placed randomly. Yeah, cool! Well, not that much, but it worked and it was fine.

I don't understand how the position update works. I mean, I was expecting to draw every single frame, but the Draw function is called only at the very beginning, when textures are loaded from content, then it just update the position by adding vectorial values.

**Next step**: I tried to implement (by my self, that's why I'm here) an animated sprite instead of the square of the first project. **The sprite is animated** (it's a walking-on-the-spot man) but it doesn't move by keyboard inputs anymore...

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, I think I found the problem. The class I downloaded has a Draw method more complicated then the one I used before...

```
batch.Draw(myTexture, Position, sourcerect, Color.White, Rotation, Origin, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, Depth);
```

... because there's a "position", but even a "origin", which I didn't try to update. I'd like even to delete it if it's not important... I'll make some try!

**Edit**: I did those tries, still the same...

---

**UPDATE**

Question cleaned, here the full code of my app:

Main class: http:// pastebin.com/EUexh9H1

Controller class: http://pastebin.com/ZEcY0DXT

Downloaded class: http://pastebin.com/H2ZDu6bs

(in this one, I just added a "Position" and the Draw call)

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to start the whole project from the beginning, to have a better and cleaner code, but it's still the same. I'm just trying to move the animated texture with a `Position += Vector2.UnitX;`, but it doesn't move at all...

What does it change with frames? I mean, when I call the draw with the Position, how frames affect it? If it does...

Comment: screenPos determines where the sprite is drawn. Change screenPos in UpdateFrame to get it to move. Try testing by just adding screenPos.X += 0.01f; so that it just slides across the screen

Comment: @WeylandYutani, thanks for the answer.
screenPos is a local variable of each function, so I added a `Vector2 Position` to the class, giving it the screenPos value at DrawFrame, then attempt to update it at UpdateFrame, but nothing changed...

Comment: And yes, I tried "Position.X += 0.01f;" too, nothing changed... I'm starting thinking it's not an update problem, I probably made some other mistake...

Comment: what is Movement set to? If it's 0,0 then nothing will ever move

Comment: try putting Position.X += 0.01f; in the Update(GameTime gameTime) method not the UpdateFrame method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was that the position was assigned inside the DrawFrame method, and at each update it restore itself, so I just moved this assignment in the costructor. It works.

So...

```
public void DrawFrame(SpriteBatch batch, int frame, Vector2 screenPos)
{
    Position = screenPos;
    int FrameWidth = myTexture.Width / framecount;
    Rectangle sourcerect = new Rectangle(FrameWidth * frame, 0, FrameWidth, myTexture.Height);
    batch.Draw(myTexture, Position, sourcerect, Color.White, Rotation, Origin, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, Depth);
}
```

... becomes...

```
public void DrawFrame(SpriteBatch batch, int frame)
{
    //Position = screenPos;
    int FrameWidth = myTexture.Width / framecount;
    Rectangle sourcerect = new Rectangle(FrameWidth * frame, 0, FrameWidth, myTexture.Height);
    batch.Draw(myTexture, Position, sourcerect, Color.White, Rotation, Origin, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, Depth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `batch.Draw` method you use `screenPos`, it is passed as a parameter, but I hope that there's a `Vector2` class variable that represents the current position of your sprite on the screen. (I don't know where you call that `DrawFrame`)
If you want to update that position you need to change that class variable in the `Update` method of your class. You don't have to add other parameters to `DrawFrame` and `UpdateFrame`, you already have what you need.

**EDIT**

In Class2 `Update` you only need to do:

```
ActiveSpriteTexture.Position += /* whatever you need */
```

I don't know what `Movement * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 15` does.

And `UpdateFrame` doesn't need `Position` parameter, that method should only update the animation of your sprite.
The same for `DrawFrame`, you have to draw the class variable Position, but you should already have done this edit.

Comment: I tried that way too, nothing different... I'll add some more code to the enrich my question details.

Comment: Ok, there must be something wrong that I don't know. Are you sure that Position actually changes?

Comment: I found out that there are 2 Vector2 used to draw the texture, see my last edit

Comment: Nope, Origin is the coordinate in texels that represents the starting point of the texture been drawn. It has nothing to do with your problem. You haven't answered my question, yet.